# Android/Parse - Querying values in a column of Class B using values in another column, and the latter are actually pointers to ObjectId of Class A

Tags: android, parsing, pointers, include, objectid

I've read many forums on this topic but none of them are specific to Android/Parse. 
I have a Parse class called "Rankingboards" that looks like this:

ObjectId   UserId   ratingsAggregate 
----------   ---------  ---------------------- 
123456   ABCDE   5.0

The "UserID" column above is actually a pointer to the "ObjectId" column in User (default class in Parse).

ObjectId 
---------- 
ABCDE

And so I wrote the following code, hoping to use whereEqualTo("UserID","ABCDE") to obtain the value of ratingsAggregate (i.e. 5.0) in getQuery("Rankingboards").

```
    List<ParseObject> ob;
    final RatingBar ratingBar;
    ratingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    String userid = user.getObjectId();
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Rankingboards");
    query.whereEqualTo("UserID", userid);
    try {
        ob = query.find();
        Log.d("POSITION",""+ob.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < ob.size(); i++) {
            Number num7 = ob.get(i).getNumber("ratingsAggregate");
            if (num7!=null) {
                ratingBar.setRating(num7.floatValue());
            }

        }

     } catch (ParseException e) {
         Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```

But this doesn't work because "UserID" is a pointer and not a string. 
I read elsewhere that I have to use "include" but I couldn't get the code to work. 
Hope someone can enlighten me.

**Notes:**
(1) I'm using a customized ListAdapter that takes in a ParseUser object (called user) as an input. That's why you see user.getObjectID() in the code and I've verified that the ObjectIDs are correct. 
(2) ob.size() is always 0 because the query isn't working. When I printed out query.size() instead, the total number of entries in Rankingboards is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution, I was having the same problem. When you use the

```
query.whereEqualTo("UserID", userid);
```

Its a pointer, when doing the equal you cant make use of a string. The way to do it is to introduce the object itself. Eliminate the

```
String userid = user.getObjectId();
```

And introduce the `user` where you had the userid

```
query.whereEqualTo("UserID", user);

List<ParseObject> ob;
    final RatingBar ratingBar;
    ratingBar = (RatingBar) v.findViewById(R.id.ratingBar);
    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = ParseQuery.getQuery("Rankingboards");
    query.whereEqualTo("UserID", user);
    try {
        ob = query.find();
        Log.d("POSITION",""+ob.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < ob.size(); i++) {
            Number num7 = ob.get(i).getNumber("ratingsAggregate");
            if (num7!=null) {
                ratingBar.setRating(num7.floatValue());
            }

        }

     } catch (ParseException e) {
         Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
```